# Get parents with ALL children that satisfy the filter in sqlachemy orm

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Let's say I have a tables Parents and Children in sqlalchemy

If I say
`db.query(Trip).join(Children,Trip.childrens).filter(Children.color=='red')`
it returns:

```
[
{
    id:10,
    childrens:[
        {
            parent_id:10,
            id:15,
            color:'red'
        },
        {
            parent_id:10,
            id:15,
            color:'red'
        }
    ]
},

{
    id:12,
    childrens:[
        {
            parent_id:12,
            id:15,
            color:'red'
        },
        {
            parent_id:12,
            id:15,
            color:'blue'
        },
        {
            parent_id:12,
            id:15,
            color:'blue'
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**However**, I need only Parents whose children have only **'red' color**

Thank you in advance.